# node form validation not called

Tags: 7, forms

I would like to add some custom validation to a node form.
But for some reason the validate function is skipped, the submit function does gets called.

```
/*
 * Custom Form settings
 */
function frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['#validate'][] = 'frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_validate';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_submit';

  dpm($form_id);
  dpm($form);

}

function frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

  drupal_set_message('error');

  form_set_error('', t('Email must be valid format if entered.'));
}

function frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('submit');
}
```

I tried several function names but nothing seems the work.

From the $form array:

```
#validate (Array, 2 elements)
0 (String, 18 characters ) node_form_validate | (Callback) node_form_validate();
1 (String, 54 characters ) frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_v... |
```

Comment: You should not be forced to add the validation or submit hook. These should be picked up by Drupal. Have you tried clearing the cache if you added those hooks after you activated your module?


Another thing. Are you sure the validate function isn't being executed? Try putting in a `exit;` after your `form_set_error();`.

Comment: I forced the validation functions because it wasn't working. Cache was cleaned several times :) adding exit; didn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

Found the problem, i use the [More buttons module](http://drupal.org/project/mb) and there seems to be something wrong with way the hook_form_alter is handled in the module, fortunately there is a [fix](http://drupal.org/node/1414898).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$form['#validate'] = array('frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_validate');
```

Comment: doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: Same code for me is working. Review your code again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem . I try to `dsm();` in `#validate` function and didn't see anything.
Your method is ok and have no problem.
they  called correctly  and run.
To sure that your function called I suggest you put `die('this is worked`);` in your callback function  . I surly say your method is correct and your function will call after your form submiting.

please test this

```
function frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['#validate'][] = 'frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_validate';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_submit';

  dpm($form_id);
  dpm($form);

}

function frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

  var_dump($form_state);
  die('this worked');
}

function frontpage_banners_form_promo_banner_node_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  var_dump($form_state);
  die('this worked');

}
```